# Check if a function uses @classmethod

Tags: python, decorator, class-method, python-decorators

**TL;DR** How do I find out whether a function was defined using `@classmethod` or something with the same effect?

---

**My problem**

For implementing a class decorator I would like to check if a method takes the class as its first argument, for example as achieved via

```
@classmethod
def function(cls, ...):
```

I found a solution to check for `@staticmethod` via the `types` module (`isinstance(foo, types.UnboundMethodType)` is `False` if the `foo` is static, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695694)), but did not find anything on how to do so for `@classmethod`

---

**Context**

What I am trying to do is something along the lines of

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    for member in cls.__dict__:
        if (isclassmethod(getattr(cls, member))):
            # do something with the method
            setattr(cls, member, modified_method)
    return cls
```

and I do not know how to implement what I called `isclassmethod` in this example

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If the object is a *method* object, and so has a [`method.__self__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#c), and that attribute is the class you got the attribute from, then it'll take the class as the first argument. It has been *bound* to the class.

Note that you already have a bound object at this point, so you don't need to pass in the class *again*, unless you first extract the original function from `method.__func__`.

Here is an illustration, the class `Foo` has a class method `bar` and a regular method `baz`, which is not bound when you access it directly on the class:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls):
...         pass
...     def baz(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> Foo.baz
<function Foo.baz at 0x1097d1e18>
>>> Foo.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.bar.__self__
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo.bar.__self__ is Foo
True
```

Calling `Foo.bar()` automatically passes in `Foo.bar.__self__` as the first argument.

If you need to test such methods, use [`inspect.ismethod()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod), and if that returns `True` test the `__self__` attribute:

```
import inspect

if inspect.ismethod(cls.method) and cls.method.__self__ is cls:
    # method bound to the class, e.g. a classmethod
```

This should work for any *custom* descriptors that work like `classmethod` does, as well.

If you need to know with certainty that the method was produced by a `classmethod` object, you'll need to look up the attributes directly in the class namespace (`cls.__dict__` or `vars(cls)`), and do so in each class in the class hierarchy in [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__):

```
def isclassmethod(method):
    bound_to = getattr(method, '__self__', None)
    if not isinstance(bound_to, type):
        # must be bound to a class
        return False
    name = method.__name__
    for cls in bound_to.__mro__:
        descriptor = vars(cls).get(name)
        if descriptor is not None:
            return isinstance(descriptor, classmethod)
    return False
```

and a full test of the above two approaches using a base class and a derived class, with a custom descriptor that binds a function the same way a `classmethod` would, but is not, itself, a `classmethod`:

```
>>> class notclassmethod:
...     def __init__(self, f):
...         self.f = f
...     def __get__(self, _, typ=None):
...         return self.f.__get__(typ, typ)
...
>>> class Base:
...     @classmethod
...     def base_cm(cls): pass
...     @notclassmethod
...     def base_ncm(cls): pass
...     def base_m(self): pass
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     @classmethod
...     def derived_cm(cls): pass
...     @notclassmethod
...     def derived_ncm(cls): pass
...     def derived_m(self): pass
...
>>> inspect.ismethod(Derived.base_cm) and Derived.base_cm.__self__ is Derived
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(Derived.base_ncm) and Derived.base_ncm.__self__ is Derived
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(Derived.base_m) and Derived.base_m.__self__ is Derived
False
>>> inspect.ismethod(Derived.derived_cm) and Derived.derived_cm.__self__ is Derived
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(Derived.derived_ncm) and Derived.derived_ncm.__self__ is Derived
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(Derived.derived_m) and Derived.derived_m.__self__ is Derived
False
>>> isclassmethod(Derived.base_cm)
True
>>> isclassmethod(Derived.base_ncm)
False
>>> isclassmethod(Derived.base_m)
False
>>> isclassmethod(Derived.derived_cm)
True
>>> isclassmethod(Derived.derived_ncm)
False
>>> isclassmethod(Derived.derived_m)
False
```

The `isclassmethod()` function correctly distinguishes between the `classmethod`  and `notclassmethod` descriptors.

---

Historical note: this answer included references to Python 2, but with Python 2 having reached EOL were removed as no longer relevant.

Comment: `inspect.ismethod(cls.method)` is False with Python 3.5+.

Comment: @fx-kirin: no, it is `True` for `classmethod` objects. You are using it with a regular function, and then you'll see `False` in *any* Python 3 release, not just 3.5+. This is covered in my answer here.

Comment: @fx-kirin: I've updated the answer to be clearer about the goal here, to detect the result of a function having been decorated with `@classmethod`, then looked up on the class.

Comment: But the example remains wrong, consider:

inspect.ismethod(Derived.derived_m) is False
inspect.ismethod(Derived().derived_m) is True

Comment: @AliAfshar: you misunderstood the answer then. `Derived.derived_m` is not a classmethod, so `ismethod()` indeed will return `False`.

Answer (score 12):

You should use [inspect.ismethod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod). It works because classmethod binds the function to the class object. See the following code:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def bar():
...             pass
...     def baz():
...             pass
...
>>> Foo.bar
<bound method type.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.baz
<function Foo.baz at 0x0000000002CCC1E0>
>>> type(Foo.bar)
<class 'method'>
>>> type(Foo.baz)
<class 'function'>
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.ismethod(Foo.bar)
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(Foo.baz)
False
```

Comment: This is only true for Python 3

Comment: Is there anything working for both Python 2 and Python 3 (personally, I use 2.7)

Comment: @hlt you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def baaz(cls):
        print "baaz"

isinstance(Foo.__dict__["baaz"], classmethod)
```

Comment: A better approach would be to use \_\_name\_\_ attribute instead of string for name. We avoid loose strings as much as possible in python. isinstance(Foo.__dict__[Foo.baaz.__name__], classmethod)

Comment: @SaimRaza while I globally agree with your comment, you have to be aware that the method's `__name__` might not necessarily match the attribute name. Since we can get the attribute name from `dir(cls)` (or, in the OP example, directly from `cls.__dict__`), using the attribute name is safer than using the method's canonical name.

Comment: could you please elaborate with an example? I am assuming we are limiting our scope to methods only. Are you referring to distinction between \_\_name\_\_ and \_\_qualname\_\_ in Python3?

Comment: examples could be either a misbehaving decorator that doesn't properly rename the wrapper function (in which case the `__name__` will be the wrapper's one, not the decorated method name), or a function set as class attribute under a distinct name, ie `Foo.bar = baaz` (where `Foo` is a class and `baaz` a function). And no, I'm not talking about `__qualname__` but about the attribute name (`bar` in the above example) vs the function's `__name__` attribute's value (`baaz` in the above example).

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers address the problem of identifying whether a method is decorated with class method from an instance of the class. Following code explores the class dict of an instance to distinguish between classmethod from other methods.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        pass

    def instance_method(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(): 
        pass

    def blas(): pass

t = MyClass()
isinstance(t.__class__.__dict__[t.class_method.__name__], classmethod)    # True
isinstance(t.__class__.__dict__[t.static_method.__name__], classmethod)   # False
isinstance(t.__class__.__dict__[t.instance_method.__name__], classmethod) # False
isinstance(t.__class__.__dict__[t.blas.__name__], classmethod)            # False
```

This will work for both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def is_classmethod(method):
    """
    Is method a classmethod?
    """
    return isinstance(getattr(method, '__self__', None), type)
```

It basically tests if `method.__self__` exists and is a class, as in Martijn's answer, but does not require access to the class itself.

Comment: This seems to be a generic type. We can't guarantee that the type would be classmethod in all cases.