# How can I override a special method defined in a metaclass with a custom classmethod?

Tags: python, overriding, metaclass, magic-methods

As an example, consider the following:

```py
class FooMeta(type):
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9000


class GoodBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    def __len__(self):
        return 9001


class BadBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9002

len(GoodBar) -> 9000
len(GoodBar()) -> 9001
GoodBar.__len__() -> TypeError (missing 1 required positional argument)
GoodBar().__len__() -> 9001
len(BadBar) -> 9000 (!!!)
len(BadBar()) -> 9002
BadBar.__len__() -> 9002
BadBar().__len__() -> 9002
```

The issue being with `len(BadBar)` returning 9000 instead of 9002 which is the intended behaviour.

This behaviour is (somewhat) documented in [Python Data Model - Special Method Lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup), but it doesn't mention anything about classmethods, and I don't really understand the interaction with the `@classmethod` decorator.

Aside from the obvious metaclass solution (ie, replace/extend `FooMeta`) is there a way to override or extend the metaclass function so that `len(BadBar) -> 9002`?

### Edit:

To clarify, in my specific use case I can't edit the metaclass, and I don't want to subclass it and/or make my own metaclass, unless it is the **only possible way** of doing this.

Comment: You can derive one metaclass from another and override the base class' methods.

Comment: @martineau I am aware, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__len__` defined in the class will always be ignored when using `len(...)` for the class itself:  when executing its operators, and methods like "hash", "iter", "len" can be roughly said to have "operator status", Python always retrieve the corresponding method from the class of the target,  by directly acessing the memory structure of the class. These dunder methods have "physical" slot in the memory layout for the class: if the method exists in the class of your instance (and in this case, the "instances" are the classes "GoodBar" and "BadBar", instances of "FooMeta"), or one of its superclasses, it is called - otherwise the operator fails.

So, this is the reasoning that applies on `len(GoodBar())`: it will call the `__len__` defined in `GoodBar()`'s class, and `len(GoodBar)` and `len(BadBar)` will call the `__len__` defined in their class, `FooMeta`

> I don't really understand the interaction with the @classmethod
> decorator.

The "classmethod" decorator creates a special descriptor out of the decorated function, so that when it is retrieved, via "getattr" from the class it is bound too, Python creates a "partial" object with the "cls" argument already in place. Just as retrieving an ordinary method from an instance creates an object with "self" pre-bound:

Both things are carried through the "descriptor" protocol - which means, both an ordinary method and a classmethod are retrieved by calling its `__get__` method. This method takes 3 parameters: "self", the descriptor itself, "instance", the instance its bound to, and "owner": the class it is ound to. The thing is that for ordinary methods (functions), when the second (instance) parameter to `__get__` is `None`, the function itself is returned. `@classmethod` wraps a function with an object with a different `__get__`: one that returns the equivalent to `partial(method, cls)`, regardless of the second parameter to `__get__`.

In other words, this simple pure Python code replicates the working of the `classmethod` decorator:

```
class myclassmethod:
    def __init__(self, meth):
         self.meth = meth
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
         return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.meth(owner, *args, **kwargs)
```

That is why you see the same behavior when calling a classmethod explicitly with `klass.__get__()` and `klass().__get__()`: the instance is ignored.

**TL;DR**: `len(klass)`  will always go through the metaclass slot, and `klass.__len__()` will retrieve `__len__`  via the getattr mechanism, and then bind the classmethod properly before calling it.

> Aside from the obvious metaclass solution (ie, replace/extend FooMeta)
> is there a way to override or extend the metaclass function so that
> len(BadBar) -> 9002?

> (...)
> To clarify, in my specific use case I can't edit the metaclass, and I
> don't want to subclass it and/or make my own metaclass, unless it is
> the only possible way of doing this.

There is no other way. `len(BadBar)` will always go through the metaclass `__len__`.

Extending the metaclass might not be all that painful, though.
It can be done with a simple call to `type` passing the new `__len__` method:

```
In [13]: class BadBar(metaclass=type("", (FooMeta,), {"__len__": lambda cls:9002})):
    ...:     pass
    

In [14]: len(BadBar)
Out[14]: 9002
```

Only if BadBar will later be combined in multiple inheritance with another class hierarchy with a *different* custom metaclass you will have to worry. Even if there are other classes that have `FooMeta` as metaclass, the snippet above will work: the dynamically created metaclass will be the metaclass for the new subclass, as the "most derived subclass".

If however, there is a hierarchy of subclasses and they have differing metaclasses, even if created by this method, you will have to combine both metaclasses in a common *subclass_of_the_metaclasses* before creating the new  "ordinary" subclass.

If that is the case, note that you can have one single paramtrizable metaclass, extending your original one (can't dodge that, though)

```
class SubMeta(FooMeta):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, *,class_len):
         cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns)
         cls._class_len = class_len
         return cls

    def __len__(cls):
        return cls._class_len if hasattr(cls, "_class_len") else super().__len__()
```

And:

```
In [19]: class Foo2(metaclass=SubMeta, class_len=9002): pass

In [20]: len(Foo2)
Out[20]: 9002
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, `len()` is going to find `__len__` on the object's type not the object itself. So `len(BadBar)` is called like `type(BadBar).__len__(BadBar)`, `FooMeta`'s `__len__` method is getting the instance which is `BadBar` here as the first parameter.

```py
class FooMeta(type):
    def __len__(cls):
        print(cls is BadBar)
        return 9000


class BadBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9002


print(len(BadBar)) # True - 9000
```

This is how it works, if you do anything with metaclass's `__len__`, other classes with that metaclass will be affected. You can not generalize it.

You can have another specific metaclass for `BadBar` and call the `cls.__len__` inside the `__len__` of the metaclass if it has one, otherwise return the default value.

```py
class BadBar_meta(type):
    def __len__(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, "__len__"):
            return cls.__len__()
        return 9000


class BadBar(metaclass=BadBar_meta):
    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9002


print(len(BadBar))  # 9002
```

Or if you just want to override only classmethods of the classes, you can check to see if the `cls` class has already defined `__len__` as a classmethod, if so call that instead.

```py
class FooMeta(type):
    def __len__(cls):
        m = cls.__len__
        if hasattr(m, "__self__"):
            return cls.__len__()

        return 9000


class GoodBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    def __len__(self):
        return 9001


class BadBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9002


print(len(GoodBar)) # 9000
print(len(BadBar))  # 9002
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228282/13944524) are more robust approaches to find classmethods.

##### After your edit:

If you don't have access to the metaclass, then you can decorate and monkey patch the metaclass:

```py
class FooMeta(type):
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9000


class GoodBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    def __len__(self):
        return 9001


class BadBar(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return 9002


def decorator(mcls):
    org_len = mcls.__len__

    def custom_len(cls):
        # check too see if it is a classmethod
        if hasattr(cls.__len__, "__self__"):
            return cls.__len__()
        return org_len(cls)

    FooMeta.__len__ = custom_len
    return mcls


FooMeta = decorator(FooMeta)

print(len(GoodBar))  # 9000
print(len(BadBar))   # 9002
```

Comment: I was experimenting with a similar approach, and it probably makes sense, but you need to be really careful with the explicit check, as I think you might end up calling the `__len__` function of the instance, not the class, if both of them are defined.

Comment: @EliasMi My question is aimed at cases when you don't want to or aren't able to modify the metaclass (this is my bad, that is not clearly stated in the original question). In either case, this is good to know, in case there really isn't any other way of doing it :)