# python typing hinting based on class methods names as literal string

Tags: python, python-typing

**TL;DR**

```py
class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self):
        pass

methods_names_type = typing.<magic_function_that_gets_all_methods_names>(SomeClass)
# methods_names_type = typing.Literal["some_method"]
```

replace the function `magic_function_that_gets_all_methods_names`

---

### Details

I have function that accepts 2 arguments: a Class (and not class instance), and list of literal strings. each of the literal strings should be a method name of the same class.

something like:

```py
def my_func(cls, cls_methods_names):
    ...
```

so if i had a class `SomeClass`, with single method `some_method`

```py
class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self):
        pass
```

the next call would get error type hint on the `non_existent`:

```py
my_func(SomeClass,
        [
            "some_method"
            , "non_existent"  # error
        ]
)
```

so far I got:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def my_func(cls: Type[T], cls_methods_names: list[<???>]):
    ...
```

help me out by replacing `<???>`, in something similar to `dir(T)`, just in static time.

so, is it possible to get a list of a class methods at static time and type hint based on it?

---

#### Typescript example

for reference, [here's a working implementation in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAUNf0ESyAssgC4AW8AJgBQCU2eBrA9G9GVbdAJaIADiGQoAduTDk%208MS3wBfHEpzkAnoORcK1GhADyAMwA8AFQB80ALzNWAbQDS-MdADWyNfEPRT0SD8cAXWhkAA9yZDE9aAAxAFcxYGlZaAB%20aCcALmgxZAA3ZAAnQOzTIIBuZUrVDS0EFHRICG5dGBsW2gMTerQMCHNqjh9KPhgAdz4QEGgAcz4C6E846CotFB4aHLAUGC84YkaoGs19hr6OmgA5beQ2tw89nsPmnU7qnEMEpJkXRDV4xJmcx0UAQbK5MbQRjWSymAA00FBFzB0AAgoVCmA1MZ3J5vBYGNk8vA%20JtcMocDg-gDgHQnn0EXYAOREFAXJlwpliWQAUVCowiEnZgQYQA)

[image]

The typescript compiler knows this is an error because *nothing here is dynamic input*

Comment: Note; a "Class Instance" is an "Object". There's no need to differentiate between Class and Object, we already know the difference.

Comment: Do you want to want to pass the ***names*** of the methods *(so, the type would just be a lost of strings)*, or the ***methods themselves***? In either case, typing won't be able to check that those methods exist on that class; you'll need to check yourself.

Comment: i need the **literal strings** representing the methods names of the class, as described above. is it possible?

Comment: Type checking is **static**. It cannot handle things you input dynamically, like contents of an array.

Comment: nothing here is a **dynamic input**. I know the difference. everything here is known and predefined(the class methods and the **literal string** which is available in the second argument). This task is possible in Typescript by the way

Comment: Parameters to functions are by definition dynamic. The function can't know what you're going to pass to it. So, a type checker can't check this. You have to do it, something like this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227724/check-if-a-function-uses-classmethod Python isn't statically typed, there are just HINTS that can be used by external programs that parse and check code for you. If you want true static typing, you don't want to use python.

Comment: as I said, nothing here is dynamic. i just want to extract information from a given type. basically `MethodsOf<T>`

Comment: @EL96NG8CNG I believe you are conflating things that Python can do and things your IDE can do. What you're describing sounds like an IDE implementation (i.e. type, method, etc validation). Until you run your program nothing is happening so how would you get a hint? And who shows that hint (hint: it's not Python, it is your IDE). How would it work if you were writing this in Notepad?

Comment: Python doesn't check typing, external type checking programs do; you run them against a code base to check if that code base has type errors. That's equivalent to checking at compile time. Python doesn't have runtime type checking.

Comment: if would use mypy, would it be possible? does mypy adds *runtime type checking*?

Comment: No, mypy is run against a code base. It is not ***part*** of the code. Python (and python code) do not check typing. I'm stopping now, you're refusing to accept that python is dynamically typed and only has type HINTS.

Answer (score 0):

### First Thoughts

The mapping between strings and method names can exist only at runtime. I imagine `my_func` contains something like:

```py
getattr(SomeClass, "some_method")
```

There is a way to type hint this, but it has to be done manually with typing.Literal:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def my_func(cls: Type[T], cls_methods_names: list[typing.Literal["some_method"]):
    ...
```

I'm not sure this is all that helpful, as now you have to specify in the type string all methods for the object.

### How did I get here?

I would suggest approaching the problem from another angle. Is `getattr` really needed here? If you're trying to provide helpful type hints, a better approach might be to consider the methods required inside my_func. Then you can use a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) to describe the methods a class needs to be valid in this function.

If you really need to use getattr, then the type could be considered simply `list[str]`, but this isn't ideal.

Comment: not very- helpful

Comment: @EL96NG8CNG Not liking the truth doesn't stop it being the truth. This answer explains that the answer to your question is "No", and then tries to help with alternatives. It is the definition of being helpful.